# Google Sheet : The result could not be auto-expanded. Please insert new columns (1)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This script import opportunities that we get. It populates rows which then calculates some numbers such as interest and stuff. However, I now have errors when populating my cells (#REF error, see pictures below). Nothing has changed so my first guess is it has do with the processing of the sheet which has become too heavy.

`

```
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen(e) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();
  menu.addItem('Créer étude', 'init');
  menu.addToUi();
}

function init() {
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  identifyJe();
  sheetMaker = ss.getActiveSheet();
  currentRow = ss.getActiveCell().getRowIndex();
  ssEtudes = SpreadsheetApp.openById(getSheetEtudesId());
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var respon se = ui.alert(
    'Ligne sélectionnée : ' + currentRow + '. Exécuter ?',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL
  );

  if (response !== ui.Button.OK) return;

  doEtude();
  doContrat();
  doPhases();
}

function doEtude(nomEtude) {
  var etudeData = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < etudeNamedRanges.length; i++) {
    var column = ss.getRangeByName(etudeNamedRanges[i]).getColumn();
    etudeData.push(sheetMaker.getRange(currentRow, column).getValue());
  }

  var destSheet = ssEtudes.getSheetByName('etudes');
  var rowToAppend = getFirstEmptyRow(destSheet, 0);

  for (var i = 0; i < etudeData.length; i++) {
    var column = ssEtudes.getRangeByName(etudeNamedRanges[i]).getColumn();
    destSheet.getRange(rowToAppend, column).setValue(etudeData[i]);
  }
}

function doContrat() {
  var contratData = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < contratNamedRanges.length; i++) {
    var column = ss.getRangeByName(contratNamedRanges[i]).getColumn();
    contratData.push(sheetMaker.getRange(currentRow, column).getValue());
  }

  var destSheet = ssEtudes.getSheetByName('contrats');
  var rowToAppend = getFirstEmptyRow(destSheet, 11);

  for (var i = 0; i < contratData.length; i++) {
    destSheet.getRange(rowToAppend, i + 4).setValue(contratData[i]);
  }
}

function doPhases() {
  var phasesCoords = getPhasesCoords();
  var phasesData = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < phasesCoords.length; i++) {
    var phaseData = getPhaseData(phasesCoords[i]);
    phaseData.unshift(i + 1);
    phasesData.push(phaseData);
  }

  var destSheet = ssEtudes.getSheetByName('phases');
  var rowToAppend = getFirstEmptyRow(destSheet, 9);
  var columns = [];

  for (var nPhase = 0; nPhase < phasesData.length; nPhase++) {
    var phaseData = phasesData[nPhase];

    for (var i = 0; i < phaseData.length; i++) {
      if (columns[i] === undefined)
        columns[i] = ssEtudes.getRangeByName(phasesNamedRanges[i]).getColumn();

      destSheet
        .getRange(rowToAppend + nPhase, columns[i])
        .setValue(phaseData[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

`

[Type of formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG82o.png)

[The results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/204Ic.png)

[The error, which translates into The result could not be auto-expanded. Please insert new columns (1).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGYaK.png)

The results actually appear for some time and disappear after a few seconds, constantly. Does it have something to do with the size of the spreadsheet ?

Comment: Then your row parameter is null.  Go figure out why.  You can use the debugger

Comment: It would be helpful to know which line causes the error

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please replace the code by a [mcve]: reproduce the error by using the shortest code to reproduce the problem, add the textual error message, describe the relevant parts of the spreadsheet, provide sample data, and the expected result .